# Devise gem: Rack app error handling request { GET /users/sign_in.js }

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, assets, precompile

I just included a js(jquery.simulate) in layout and declared to precompile in development.rb. But when I try to run rails app,it breaks with this error : `ActionController::UnknownFormat: ActionController::UnknownFormat.`

Here is the full trace:

Started GET "/users/sign_in.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-07 12:24:18 +0530E, [2017-07-07T12:24:18.699146 #31265] ERROR -- sentry: ** [Raven] Not sending event due to previous failure(s).
E, [2017-07-07T12:24:18.699306 #31265] ERROR -- sentry: ** [Raven] Failed to submit event: ActionController::UnknownFormat: ActionController::UnknownFormat
2017-07-07 12:24:18 +0530 severity=FATAL, 2017-07-07 12:24:18 +0530 severity=FATAL, ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):2017-07-07 12:24:18 +0530 severity=FATAL, 2017-07-07 12:24:18 +0530 severity=FATAL, responders (2.3.0) lib/action_controller/respond_with.rb:207:in `respond_with'
devise (4.2.0) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:12:in`new'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:188:in`process_action'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in`block in process_action'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in`block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in`**run_callbacks**'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in`run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in`process_action'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in`block in instrument'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in`instrument'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:248:in`process_action'
activerecord (5.0.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:126:in`process'
actionview (5.0.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in`dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:262:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in`dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:16:in`block in '
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:46:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in`block in serve'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `each'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in`serve'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:725:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
apipie-rails (0.3.7) lib/apipie/static_dispatcher.rb:65:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
omniauth (1.3.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
omniauth (1.3.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in`call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
omniauth (1.3.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in`call!'
omniauth (1.3.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
omniauth (1.3.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
omniauth (1.3.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in`call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
omniauth (1.3.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in`call!'
omniauth (1.3.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
omniauth (1.3.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
omniauth (1.3.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in`call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
omniauth (1.3.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in`call!'
omniauth (1.3.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
bullet (5.5.0) lib/bullet/rack.rb:12:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
apipie-rails (0.3.7) lib/apipie/extractor/recorder.rb:132:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
jquery-fileupload-rails (0.4.7) lib/jquery/fileupload/rails/middleware.rb:14:in `_call'
jquery-fileupload-rails (0.4.7) lib/jquery/fileupload/rails/middleware.rb:10:in`call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:30:in`traced_call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:32:in`traced_call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
omniauth (1.3.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:403:in`call_app!'
omniauth-saml (1.7.0) lib/omniauth/strategies/saml.rb:135:in `other_phase'
omniauth (1.3.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:185:in`call!'
omniauth (1.3.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
omniauth (1.3.2) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:63:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in`catch'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:222:in `context'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:216:in`call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in`call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
activerecord (5.0.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:553:in`call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in`block in call'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in`_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in`call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in`call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in`call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in`call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in`call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
railties (5.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in`call_app'
railties (5.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
request_store (1.3.2) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:9:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
rack-cors (0.4.1) lib/rack/cors.rb:81:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
sentry-raven (2.3.0) lib/raven/integrations/rack.rb:50:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
railties (5.0.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/deflater.rb:35:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.18.0.329) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
puma (3.7.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:226:in `call'
puma (3.7.0) lib/puma/server.rb:578:in`handle_request'
puma (3.7.0) lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
puma (3.7.0) lib/puma/server.rb:275:in`block in run'

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Error is mentioned in the header itself.  Rack app error handling request { GET /users/sign_in.js }

Comment: Can you put the full stack trace from the console?